# Came across a circuit with current flowing from Low to High potential across a resistor (electrons moving from high to low potential)

Tags: electric-current, semiconductor-physics, electronics

This is the circuit of small signal analysis for a BJT amplifier.

The current shouldn't flow at all. How is it even flowing ?

I'm attaching the snap shot of this particular moment from the video lecture.
[image]

According to this video, the current gm*Vin is flowing out of the circuit, from low to high potential points ( given they are moving from the grounded points to the collector point )

Answer (score 2):

What you have drawn is the equivalent circuit for a small signal response.

[image]

I can only guess what the original circuit looks like but it might well be that the bottom end of the load resistor $R_{\rm L}$ is connected to the positive terminal of the voltage source $+V_{\rm S}$ which provides the bias voltages/currents.

This means that the actual current is the bias current (flowing from a positive to a negative potential) minus a small signal current due to the small signal input voltage to the device $v_{\rm in}$ with $V_{\rm s} \gg v_{\rm in}$ and flowing from a high potential to a lower potential..